# Selecting line from file by using "startswith" and "next" commands

Tags: python, readlines, startswith

I have a file from which I want to create a list ("timestep") from the numbers which appear after each line "ITEM: TIMESTEP" so:

```
timestep = [253400, 253500, .. etc]
```

Here is the sample of the file I have:

```
ITEM: TIMESTEP
253400
ITEM: NUMBER OF ATOMS
378
ITEM: BOX BOUNDS pp pp pp
-2.6943709180241954e-01 5.6240920636804063e+01
-2.8194230631882372e-01 5.8851195163321044e+01
-2.7398090193568775e-01 5.7189372326936599e+01
ITEM: ATOMS id type q x y z 
16865 3 0 28.8028 1.81293 26.876 
16866 2 0 27.6753 2.22199 27.8362 
16867 2 0 26.8715 1.04115 28.4178 
16868 2 0 25.7503 1.42602 29.4002 
16869 2 0 24.8716 0.25569 29.8897 
16870 3 0 23.7129 0.593415 30.8357 
16871 3 0 11.9253 -0.270359 31.7252 
ITEM: TIMESTEP
253500
ITEM: NUMBER OF ATOMS
378
ITEM: BOX BOUNDS pp pp pp
-2.6943709180241954e-01 5.6240920636804063e+01
-2.8194230631882372e-01 5.8851195163321044e+01
-2.7398090193568775e-01 5.7189372326936599e+01
ITEM: ATOMS id type q x y z 
16865 3 0 28.8028 1.81293 26.876 
16866 2 0 27.6753 2.22199 27.8362 
16867 2 0 26.8715 1.04115 28.4178 
16868 2 0 25.7503 1.42602 29.4002 
16869 2 0 24.8716 0.25569 29.8897 
16870 3 0 23.7129 0.593415 30.8357 
16871 3 0 11.9253 -0.270359 31.7252
```

To do this I tried to use "startswith" and "next" commands at once and it didn't work. Is there other way to do it? I send also the code I'm trying to use for that:

```
timestep = []
with open(file, 'r') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
    for line in lines:
        line = line.split()
        if line[0].startswith("ITEM: TIMESTEP"):
            timestep.append(next(line))     
            print(timestep)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The logic is to decide whether to append the current `line` to `timestep` or not. So, what you need is a variable which tells you append the current `line` when that variable is TRUE.

```
timestep = []
append_to_list = False # decision variable

with open(file, 'r') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
    for line in lines:
        line = line.strip() # remove "\n" from line
        if line.startswith("ITEM"):
            # Update add_to_list
            if line == 'ITEM: TIMESTEP':
                append_to_list = True
            else:
                append_to_list = False
        else:
            # append to list if line doesn't start with "ITEM" and append_to_list is TRUE
            if append_to_list:
                timestep.append(line)
print(timestep)
```

output:

```
['253400', '253500']
```

Answer (score 2):

So the problem with your code is subtle. You have a list `lines` which you iterate over, but you can't call `next` on a list.

Instead, turn it into an explicit iterator and you should be fine

```py
timestep = []
with open(file, 'r') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
    lines_iter = iter(lines)
    for line in lines_iter:
        line = line.strip()  # removes the newline
        if line.startswith("ITEM: TIMESTEP"):
            timestep.append(next(lines_iter, None))  # the second argument here prevents errors
                                                     # when ITEM: TIMESTEP appears as the
                                                     # last line in the file
        print(timestep)
```

I'm also not sure why you included `line.split`, which seems to be incorrect (in any case `line.split()[0].startswith('ITEM: TIMESTEP')` can never be true, since the split will separate `ITEM:` and `TIMESTEP` into separate elements of the resulting list.)

---

For a more robust answer, consider grouping your data based on when the line begins with `ITEM`.

```py
def process_file(f):
    ITEM_MARKER = 'ITEM: '
    item_title = '(none)'
    values = []
    for line in f:
        if line.startswith(ITEM_MARKER):
            if values:
                yield (item_title, values)
            item_title = line[len(ITEM_MARKER):].strip()  # strip off the marker
            values = []
        else:
            values.append(line.strip())
    if values:
        yield (item_title, values)
```

This will let you pass in the whole file and will lazily produce a set of values for each `ITEM: <whatever>` group. Then you can aggregate in some reasonable way.

```py
with open(file, 'r') as f:
    groups = process_file(f)
aggregations = {}
for name, values in groups:
    aggregations.setdefault(name, []).extend(values)
print(aggregations['TIMESTEP'])  # this is what you want
```

Comment: Note that you can likely skip `f.readlines` completely and simply operate over `f`

Comment: There is a split command because I wanted to avoid having '\n' after each list element. I know that also strip() can be used so I was playing with them just to see how it will influence the result.

Comment: @kata248 I added a section about making this a more robust solution.

Answer (score 2):

First - I don't like this, because it doesn't scale. You can only get the first immediately following line nicely, anything else will be just ugh...

But you asked, so ... `for x in lines` will create an iterator over lines and use that to keep the position. You don't have access to that iterator, so `next` will not be the next element you're expecting. But you can make your own iterator and use that:

```
lines_iter = iter(lines)
for line in lines_iter:
    # whatever was here
                timestep.append(next(line_iter))
```

However, if you ever want to scale it... `for` is not a good way to iterate over a file like this. You want to know what is in the next/previous line. I would suggest using `while`:

```
timestep = []
with open('example.txt', 'r') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
i = 0
while i < len(lines):
    if line[i].startswith("ITEM: TIMESTEP"):
       i += 1
       while not line[i].startswith("ITEM: "):
           timestep.append(next(line))     
           i += 1
    else:
       i += 1
```

This way you can extend it for different types of ITEMS of variable length.

Answer (score 1):

You can use enumerate to help with index referencing. We can check to see if the string `ITEM: TIMESTEP` is in the previous line then add the integer to our timestep list.

```
timestep = []
with open('example.txt', 'r') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
    for i, line in enumerate(lines):
        if "ITEM: TIMESTEP" in lines[i-1]:
            timestep.append(int(line.strip()))
            print(timestep)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I used you code for other purpose too. Could you tell me how I can from certain line for example "ITEM: TIMESTEP" append all the lines which are after? It can be in a form of a string for each line. I'm asking because I would like to add/modify a piece of code to the one you wrote.

Comment: You could create a boolean `flag` and change it from `False` to `True` if `"ITEM: TIMESTEP"` has been seen.